# Is there a way to return null in JSON response?

Tags: json, laravel-5

I want to return response with 404 error code and whit null in body, but when I try

```
response()->json(null, 404);              // return empty object {}
response()->json(json_encode(null), 404); // return string "null"
response()->json(0, 404);                 // return number 0
response()->json(false, 404);             // return false
```

I don't want to get empty body (like in http code 204) - I want to get `null` - in the same way I get `false` (it is not string - it is special/keyword value).

The `null` is valid [json](https://jsonlint.com/) - it is possible to return NULL as json response (for 404) in Laravel?

Comment: can you put the expected response in body ?

Comment: do you want to return "null" in body or empty response ?

Comment: @Googlian — They want `null`.

Comment: null in body and 404 header ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple return the `response()` method.

```
return response("null", 404)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```